# How to open a particular Facebook post in Facebook iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, url-scheme

So I get this data from graph search:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon

which has post Id and the user Id. How can I use it to launch the Facebook iOS app and make the app go to that specific post?

The URL schemes from wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes‎ are not working for this.

Comment: try to fetch 'link' tag in the json - For Eg: You have https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=638276462864647&set=pcb.638276969531263&type=1&relevant_count=3 and open it in a webView or in a safari browser.